# Python subprocess File not found

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to find the file type using file with subprocess

```
    cwdir = os.getcwd()
    Fileinput=cwdir+"/"+'testfile.zip'
    print "Current Directory %s"% cwdir
    Fileformat=subprocess.Popen('file' + Fileinput)
```

I get OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. I verified and the file does exist in the path. 
Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add space between `'file'` and `fileinput`

```
Fileformat = subprocess.Popen('file ' + Fileinput)
#                                  ^
```

Otherwise, `file/current/path/testfile.zip` is treated as executable path instead of `file`.

Or use following form:

```
Fileformat = subprocess.Popen(['file', Fileinput])
```

you have to pass `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to `Popen` and read using `Fileformat.stdout.read()` if you want get output of the command.

How about using `subprocess.check_output`?

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(['file', '/etc/passwd'])
'/etc/passwd: ASCII text\n'
```

Comment: I still get the same error even after adding the space for 'file '. However I changed it to check_output and it works. Thanks.